# How to get default proxy settings in java program (not applet)?

Tags: java, networking, proxy, network-programming

I've just gone through the web searching how to get system proxy settings. I've found:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
```

but it does nothing. I have a proxy settings in my corpo network but the code that shows the proxy list:

```
ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("http://foo/bar")))
```

says it's only one proxy "DIRECT". I don't want to provide the proxy settings by hand when it's already done. Is there a way to make JVM to provide proxy settings from OS/browser to the Java program (not applet)?

Ok,I think I got it: my browser proxy is set up by some script, defined in:

> Internet Properties/Connections/LAN Settings/Use automatic
>   configuration script

Probably, that's why Java cannot list proxy properly, even it's used in the browser. Sad, that JVM cannot parse the script and provide these settings...

Comment: Note that some browsers do not set system-wide proxy

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the property:
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
in the main method, otherwise it get no effect, then call the getDefault() as you described.