# Java get the default proxy

Tags: java, http, proxy

Is there a way to get the "behind-the-scenes" proxy in Java? The one specified with `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`.

If I do:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

It automatically connects through the values set above. I can also specify a Proxy (`HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);`). But how can I specify the default proxy?

For example, I have a method and want to open a connection with the "default proxy" (which does the same thing as `Proxy.NO_PROXY` if `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` aren't set)? I could use

```
(HttpURLConnection) ((proxy == null) ? url.openConnection() : url.openConnection(proxy))
```

but is there away to do

```
(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy == null ? [the default proxy] : proxy)
```

---

I tried getting the default proxy with

```
public static Proxy getCurrentHTTPProxy(Proxy defaultProxy) {
    String proxyHost = System.getProperty("http.proxyHost");
    String proxyPort = System.getProperty("http.proxyPort");
    if (proxyHost == null || proxyPort == null) {
        return defaultProxy;
    }
    return new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, Integer.parseInt(proxyPort)));
}
```

But I still need to make a special case and check for https proxy settings. (if the URL is http, call getCurrentHTTPProxy, if the URL is https, call getCurrentHTTPSProxy). I also looked into ProxySelector (like here [How to get default proxy settings in java program (not applet)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904088/how-to-get-default-proxy-settings-in-java-program-not-applet)) but that seems too clumsy for something like this.

Lastly, I tried looking into openjdk's implementation, which seems to open a connection with the default proxy if the passed parameter is null, but when I tried it on the Sun JVM and that gives a NullPointerException.

Comment: The no-argument `openConenction()` call is the normal/right way to do this. Is there a reason you don't want to use that?

Comment: @MelNicholson it just seems clumsy (as if overloaded methods should all do the same thing, and not rely on one version to get what I want) :P I was wondering if there's a way I could explicitly specify it